# How to programmatically enter a password inside a password protected PDF file?

Tags: swift, macos, pdf

I am making a os x application in swift that can programmatically 'crack' a password by trying each number from 1-99999999. I know the location of the PDF file in string format. How can I,

1. Test if the PDF file is password protected?
2. If it is, try if a password is correct?

Thanks for helping me! 
(It is just for learning purposes not for real hacking;) )

Comment: You are aware of the fact that there might be letters in the password as well?

Comment: Yes I know, I might focus on that later, but for now I would just like to keep it simple with Integer only passwords. (and for that I only need to change the guessing algorithm, not the code that tries if a password is correct ;)

Comment: You should not focus on that later since that **BREAKS** your entire idea, it is very hard (-> impossible) to crack a password via pure bruteforce - a 7-letter password offers a few billion or even trillion options.

Comment: I know, but the password protected files are made by myself so I know the password is integer only. It wasn't my purpose to really make a brute force attack app, just to try if I could crack my own made pdf file, for learning purposes.

Comment: Okay, then you should show what you have tried so far - do you have anything that demonstrates your attempt of entering password and checking for protection?

Comment: The things I have so far are: a AMPathPopUpButton where you define the location of your pdf file. By checking if that location ends with ".pdf" I check it is a PDF file. I really couldn't find any info about using that file location (format: "~/Desktop/secret.pdf") to enter a password inside that PDF file. I have searched for hours but in every example it was about displaying the content of the PDF and nothing about the password.

Comment: If all you wish to do is crack a password you made up yourself, then why involve a PDF file?

Comment: Thanks crd, but how would I manage that in swift? Which libary's would I use? And coulf you maybe give a code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for on [this apple site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword). 
Here is how I managed to get it work:

1. first you transform the filepath string into NSURL(and make CFURL of that) like this:

   ```
   let path : NSString = filepath as NSString        
   let thePath = path.stringByExpandingTildeInPath   
   let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(thePath)   
   let CFUrl = url as CFURL
   ```
2. You import CoreGraphics and CoreFoundation and then make a document like this:

   ```
   var document : CGPDFDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(CFUrl)
   ```
3. Now you can use the CoreGraphics methods to check if it is unlocked or not and to enter a password like this:

   ```
   if CGPDFDocumentIsUnlocked(document) {
       //true if there is NO password   
   }    
   if CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(document, "password here") {      
       //returns true if the password is correct   
   }
   ```

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora That is a new question of its own, so I think it would be better to ask that one seperately as my original question from 4 years ago had nothing to do with showing anything.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora: How did you manage to show the un protected document on the view?

Comment: @AakashWadhwa-iOSDeveloper as I said last time, that is a separate question. If you want to be helped by the users of this forum, ask it separately as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

**Enter PDF password programmatically in Swift 5**

```
    let pdfURL = //Your pdf url
    let password = "12345"
    
    let document = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)
    document?.unlock(withPassword: password)
    pdfView.document = document
```

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file format is documented in the [Adobe/ISO specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Using that information you should be able to read in a PDF file, determine if it is password protected, and try out passwords. Won't be a small task, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docotic.Pdf](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library) dll to check whether the pdf is password protected or not.

```
bool isPasswordProtected = PdfDocument.IsPasswordProtected(filePath);
```

to Open the pdf

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(filePath, password))
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(filePath))
```